# How to convert from response 'set-cookie' header to request 'cookie' header in spray?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm attempting to use [spray-client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/spray-client/) and [spray-httpx](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/spray-httpx/request-building/) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert 'set-cookie' headers from `HttpResponse` to a 'cookie' header that I'd like to set on an `HttpRequest`

```
val responseSetCookieHeaders = response.headers filter { _.name == "Set-Cookie" }
...
val requestCookieHeader:HttpHeader = ???
...
addHeader(requestCookieHeader) ~> sendReceive ~> { response => ??? }
```

I do see `spray.http.HttpHeaders.Cookie`, but I see no way to convert from an instance of `HttpHeader` to `HttpCookie`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HttpHeaders.Cookie` is a case class with an `unapply` method. So you can extract it from response with a simple function:

```
def getCookie(name: String): HttpHeader => Option[HttpCookie] = {
  case Cookie(cookies) => cookies.find(_.name == name)
}
```

That's a bit more general case, but i think the solution is clear.

I would do this in the following way:

```
// some example response with cookie
val httpResponse = HttpResponse(headers = List(`Set-Cookie`(HttpCookie("a", "b"))))

// extracting HttpCookie
val httpCookie: List[HttpCookie] = httpResponse.headers.collect { case `Set-Cookie`(hc) => hc }

// adding to client pipeline
val pipeline = addHeader(Cookie(httpCookie)) ~> sendReceive
```

Comment: from what i can see the matching should be done on `Set-Cookie`:
val responseSetCookieHeader:HttpHeader = ???;
responseSetCookieHeader match { case HttpHeader.`Set-Cookie`(c) => println(c.content) }. thank you for putting me on the right track!

Comment: basically, i ended-up doing: responseSetCookieHeaders map { case HttpHeaders.`Set-Cookie`(c) => s"${c.name}=${c.content}" } mkString "; "  if you update your answer with matching on "Set-Cookie" instead of "Cookie" I'll accept it

Comment: just add one last line showing how to convert from List[HttpCookie] to HttpHeader: `HttpHeaders.Cookie(httpCookie)`